# Update page title for edited questions after a live refresh

Tags: feature-request, edits, title, live-refresh

This is a very small thing, but when a question is edited and the title is changed in the edit, if somebody loads the new question by clicking the grey bar instead of reloading the page, the title in the browser stays the same.

I am a JavaScript developer, so I know for a fact that this can easily be fixed, so that when the grey bar is clicked, the title updates if it was changed in the question.

Comment: Grey bar? Which grey bar?

Comment: @Bakuriu Presumably the one that says "This post has been edited, click to load".

Comment: @BradleyDotNET It doesn't occurr to me often so I don't remember the color of that message. It would have been better to explain it that way or provide a screen shot.

Comment: *+1*: I don't know why it is the way it is. If the body and title were *both* edited, it'd make more sense to update both of them, rather than just the body.

Comment: @Bakuriu, I agree. I click it a lot, so I know :). Just trying to provide the information, no offense intended.